# Sorting data by total

Tags: excel

I'm presenting a spreadsheet in a meeting that I've been working on next week, though I'm new to excel and need some help tidying it up before the presentation.

I'm working on a spreadsheet where details of customer enquiries are entered into a table into a left, and a breakdown of the data is drawn on the right.

The issue:

On the left side of the spreadsheet, there is a table where new data is entered daily.
in Column B, staff names are listed.

On the right, in Column I, their names are drawn with the total times shown in the next column, j.
I've set this up currently with the following formula, though this only organises them alphabetically,

```
i =SORT(UNIQUE('Oct23'!$B$2:$B$597))


j =SORT(COUNTIFS('Oct23'!$B$2:$B$597,I8,'Oct23'!$F$2:$F$597,"Yes"))
```

How could I have this drawn in order of most appearing total?

Also, I'm curious how I can data automatically sorted? My other breakdowns can be sorted through Data > Sort by Descending, though this has to be done manually each time a new row of data is entered into the left table.

Comment: Post some sample data using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** so that it can reproducible to provide a formula, showing the expected output as well